# Using Descriptive Statistics gem on active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed [descriptive statistics](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/descriptive_statistics) successfully and in attempting to use the methods provided (like Variance etc) , it keeps shooting out undefined method 'variance'. I thought the methods were just built in and could be used straight away.

Scores_controller.rb

```
def index                                         
      statsD = User.all.extend(DescriptiveStatistics)
      @var = Score.variance(&:strokes) 
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
Variance:  <%= @var %>
```

I'm attempting to apply the stats to my table full of scores. Please help.

Comment: what is the datatype of strokes?

Comment: I just created a sample app using descriptive statistics you can take a look at it https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_descriptive_statistics I hope that this helps

Comment: @MZaragoza Thanks! is that rails? It looks kinda funny

Comment: in fact that is rails what part looks funny?

Comment: I am still interested in knowing what datatype is strokes

Comment: @MZaragoza They're integers... The views part ... Ive added those bits but it gives a undefined method `decent_configuration' for ApplicationController:Class error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend DescriptiveStatistics for the model that you are trying to use. It looks like you are extending `User` but want to use `Score`

```
def index                                         
  scores = Score.all.extend(DescriptiveStatistics)
  @variance = scores.variance(&:strokes) 
end
```

now in your view do

```
Variance:  <%= @variance %>
```

take a look at this example app
https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_descriptive_statistics